# Angular directive ngIf is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

We are trying to pass data from one component to another and below is the approach we are taking. When there is no data we want to show the error message

```
<div *ngIf="showGlobalError">
      <h6>The reporting project doesn't have any Shippable Items</h6>
  </div>
```

and the component.ts is like

```
showGlobalError = true;
constructor(private psService: ProjectShipmentService, private pdComp: ProjectDetailsComponent) {
    this.psService.tDate.subscribe(x => this.cachedResults = x);
  }
  ngOnInit() {    }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.cachedResults.length > 0 && this.count <= 1) {
        this.showGlobalError = false;
        this.populateArrays();
        this.count++;
      }
  }    
  populateArrays() {
    this.reportingProject = [this.pdComp.rProjectNumber];
    this.projectSalesOrder = this.pdComp.rSalesOrder;
    this.clearFilter();
  ........
```

The issue is Even though there is data in the this.cachedResults that is this.cachedResults.length not equal to '0' for few seconds 'The reporting project doesn't have any Shippable Items' is shown in the page and then shows the data I am not sure if this something with the ngDoCheck() is causing this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: For starters showglobalerrors starts off as true so the message will always show first.

Comment: 1st line showGlobalError = true; make it false, when length = 0 mark it true

Answer (score 0):

Since, the default value of `showGlobalError` is true, the page load shows the error message.

Please make it by default false and make it true when `this.cachedResults.length` is `0` or `this.cachedResults` is `undefined` or `this.cachedResults` is `null`.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than subscribing in the code you can use the async pipe in your template

```
items$ = this.psService.tDate;

showGlobalError$ = this.items$.pipe(map(results => !results || !results.length));

constructor(private psService: ProjectShipmentService, private pdComp: ProjectDetailsComponent) { }
```

and in your template

```
<div *ngIf="showGlobalError$ | async">
  <h6>The reporting project doesn't have any Shippable Items</h6>
</div>

<ng-template *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
  Do stuff with {{item | json}}
</ng-template>
```

This manages your subscription for you and fixes the memory leak you have in your code with the subscription you don't unsubscribe from.

Take a look at alibrary I wrote for this sort of thing, make caching data a lot easier. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb